# Android - how EditText behaves as label and textField

Tags: android, android-edittext

how to change EditText field background on button click? In a view mode it just appear as a label without any border and after button click it goes to edit mode with a border.
Thanks

Comment: Why you are not using FrameLayout. Where you can keep TextView and EditText same time and can show only one at a time. No need to play with background of EditTxt, it will create problem with focus and listener.

Answer (score 2):

Use your edittext as below in main.xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:text="hello"
        android:background="#000"
        android:padding="5dip"/>
```

Put below code (**bg.xml**) in **drawable** folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">   
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>    
    <corners android:radius="3dip" />
    <stroke android:color="#00f"
        android:width="2dip" />
</shape>
```

Write Button Click listener as below in Java file

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
        }
    });
```

I hope it may help you. **You have to modify colors as you require.**

Answer (score 0):

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                editText.setBackgroundColor("to ur specified colour");
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing editText as a label, You can make background transparent as per following....

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

And if you want border when clicked then you can set image with border as a background programatically...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a selector for the background of the editText, with the focused image the default focused image and the normal image just transparency. Then set the selector as the background of the EditText and you shouldn't need an OnClickListener or any programmatic fix.